# Laravel Passport error when login, use together with Laravel Socialite

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I'm building 2 apps which 1 for the OAuth by using Laravel Passport and another app is using the Laravel Socialite with the Provider from https://socialiteproviders.com/Laravel-Passport/

I have set up all the route and have ran `passport:install`

[image]

[image]

And at the second application, I have install Laravel Socialite with provider.

Provider settings are also set in config and .env file
[image]

But when I try to login, it show error as below, but I confirm that I can login normally using web in OAuth application

```
Client error: `POST http://localhost:8002/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}
```

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check oAuth provider settings!

Comment: @Ramanath hi, I have set all provider settings in the config and environment file already

Comment: which provider yields this error?

Comment: You're using socialite. right? Usually, these errors are from the providers end due to the wrong configuration.

Comment: @Ramanath right, im using socialite. but I have checked every parameter and they are correct. what else can I check?